# HAAR Cascade in Python 3.6 Open

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I'm trying to build a Facial Recognition Software in python with OpenCV. I'm using HAAR cascade but every time I run the program I get a traceback error. I'm wondering if I messed up by not typing in the correct file location or if I'm just doing something wrong somewhere else in the code. For File location, I've tried

```
detectFace = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Desktop/Fall 17/Intelligent System/Final Project/Facial Recognition/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

and

```
detectFace = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

**My Code:**

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

detectFace = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')


Id= input('enter user id')
sampleNum=0;

while(True):
    ret, img = cam.read();
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detectFace.detectMultiScale(gray,1,3,5);
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:


        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

        sampleNum = sampleNum+1;


        cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+Id+"."
        +str(sampleNum)+".jpg",gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])



    cv2.imshow('faces',img);
    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break



    elif sampleNum>20:
        break
cam.realease()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/claws/Desktop/Fall 17/Intelligent Systems/Final 
Project/Facial Recognition/dataSet_Creator.py", line 16, in <module>
faces = detectFace.detectMultiScale(gray,1,3,5);
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-
python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215) 
!empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale
```

Comment: I've reverted the last edit which removed your traceback, but you need to correct the indentation in your code - it's very messed up. Pro Tip - If you get a notification that someone else has made an edit suggestion to your post, check it before approving. There are many, *many* bad edit suggestions.

Comment: Okay thanks. And this is my first coming to this site so I was kinda confused how to do the indentations on it but I ensure you it is fine in my python. Thanks for your help also!

Comment: You indentation may be correct, but it's *not* in your post. As indentation is crucial in Python, it is hard for anybody to help with the code in the state it is. To get the indentation correct, paste your code into the question, select it all and then use the `{}` button to apply code formatting to it all (it actually just indents all the code a further four spaces)